# .NET MarkLogic API development on semantic triple store

Tags: marklogic

Which .NET library is good for connecting with Marklogic server for semantic API development? Also which package is good for developing REST API on RDF triple store?

Answer (score 1):

MarkLogic deprecated their XCC library for .NET

You should try [XQRS](http://consulting.xmllondon.com/xqrs/) to build RESTful Services on MarkLogic Server, you can make beautiful services that behave exactly the way you want them to with ease via XQuery Annotations.

Answer (score 1):

Use XQRS

https://consulting.xmllondon.com/xqrs

Its solid, and has tonnes of docs

Comment: looks pretty nice. But, I want to develop a REST API wrapper on top of MarkLogic triple store using C# language. Can you write any specific to this?

Answer (score 1):

MarkLogic already provides a REST API providing access to RDF triples.  See:

http://docs.marklogic.com/REST/client/semantics

The builtin REST API implements the W3C Graph Store HTTP Protocol.

If the builtin REST API doesn't meet your requirements, it might be better to provide feedback on your requirements to MarkLogic Support instead of investing in developing a custom REST API.

If the requirements do justify a custom REST API, you can implement the endpoints in SJS (Server-Side JavaScript) or XQuery.

In either case, you would then use the .Net HTTP libraries to make HTTP requests to the endpoints.

Hoping that helps,